# ¿Dónde se usa la locución "igual y"?

Tags: gramática, diferencias-regionales, locuciones

¿Alguien conoce acerca del origen de la locución **igual y**? ¿Se usa en tu lugar de origen? Esta locución es ampliamente usada en México, por lo menos en el centro, y se usa como sinónimo de *tal vez*, *es probable*, *a lo mejor*, o como frase introductoria de una proposición/sugerencia.

Ejemplo 1:

> —¿Crees que mañana tengamos clase?
>   —Igual y no. (Posiblemente no, Tal vez no.) El maestro está enfermo.

Ejemplo 2:

> —Igual y llueve mañana, mejor no hagamos planes.

Ejemplo 3:

> —Podemos ir a comer comida china.
>   —O igual (y) podemos comer pizza.

Nótese que en el ejemplo 2 se está usando presente indicativo (llueve) en lugar de presente subjuntivo (llueva), no hay posibilidad de usar llueva, como si usaramos tal vez o posiblemente.

> Tal vez llueva mañana, mejor no hagamos planes.

En el ejemplo 3 se está usando a modo de introducir una sugerencia. Siendo "y" una palabra alternativa.

Comment: Aquí en España no la he oído. Lo más cerca que he escuchado es una versión del segundo ejemplo: "igual va y llueve mañana".

Comment: Igual y si la he escuchado en Monterrey, Mexico

Comment: No se usa en Argentina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según el diccionario de americanismos de ASALE, se usa solamente en México:

> **[igual](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=igual)**
>
> I. c. ǁ **~ y**. locución adverbial. *Mx.* Quizás.

Ahora mismo no encuentro ninguna aparición de la expresión tal cual ni en el CORDE ni en el CREA, así que no puedo decir nada acerca de su posible origen. La única hipótesis que tengo es que venga originada por una frase de este estilo:

> Aunque, como dice Juan, da igual. Sí, para todo efecto práctico, da igual... y no.
>
> - María Luisa Puga, "La forma del silencio", México (1987)

La frase da a entender que podría dar igual o no, lo que a su vez podría haber generado el "igual y no" del habla coloquial, significando "a lo mejor no".